# Sales Force SQL string to date convertion

Tags: sql, salesforce

I have written following conversion that works okey in T-SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM thetable
WHERE convert(datetime, SomeDate, 103) >= '2020-10-01 00:00:00.000
```

When downloading data from Sales Force using Azure Data Factory, I pasted the same command and it has returned syntax error.
Is there another SQL dialect that Sales Force recognizes ? If so, how can I rewrite varchar(string) to date conversion to use it in WHERE statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by removing conversion and changing date format:

```
SELECT * FROM thetable
WHERE SomeDate >= '2020-10-01T00:00:00Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

2020-10-01T00:00:00Z

Just like that, no apostrophes

Comment: Thank you for the link! Unfortunately it did not help. I think the error is on data convertion step. In the documentation I could only find how to use convertCurrency. Is there a way to convert string type to date using SOQL ?

Comment: What's your SOQL query exactly and what error you're getting. There are some date functions https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm but I don't think anything for string -> date. You'd need to do it in the query text proper or maybe `WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) = 2020 AND CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) = 10 AND DAY_IN_MONTH(CreatedDate) = 1`. Messy

Comment: Oh, I just made it work with putting date format as you provided but in apostrophes and omitting conversion to date! It was weird since I am Azure Data Factory recognized it as string. Sorry, don't want to share exact query since it is on my employers data